# How to run Java Swing Application outside IDE

Tags: java, swing, deployment

I created a small swing application having some GUI components and some java code. When I run it from the IDE, I see GUI open and it works as expected. Now I want to distribute this application to others and it will be run on different machines. I am just wondering as how could I distribute it?

Under project folder, I see following -

```
-dist
--lib
----some required jar files
--project.jar

-build
--classes
----packagename folder -->UI classes
----projectnamefolder--->projectname.class
--empty
--generated-sources
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with jdk 1.7. Earlier I was able to distribute such apps and they worked from command line or by double clicking .jar file.

Is there anything different in case of swing apps? Kindly suggest.

If I run from command prompt the jar file located under dist folder, it doesn't throw any error but no GUI appears.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're not swallowing exceptions?

Comment: an 'executable' jar should be sufficient

Comment: What is exact command you are using to launch it, and how you handle errors? I guess that application crashed but error is not printed on console. Use logging to file to make sure that it do what it should do

Comment: I don't see `Class-Path: lib/swing-layout-1.0.jar` in manifest file. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: No `dist/README.TXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these Steps in [LINK](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) and other system will need JRE to run.

I think you are missing `swing-layout-1.0.jar`

To add the Swing Layout Extensions library:

Right-click the project's Libraries node and choose Add Library.

In the Add Library dialog box, select Swing Extensions Layout and click Add Library.

Click OK to close the Project Properties dialog box.

---

Additional to doing what Shiv suggested, I followed [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/403965/java/java/Netbeans-Experts) , and it clicked to me as what was i doing wrong.

Comment: Shiv, you are right, I was missing `swing-layout-1.0.jar`. Have added it. Checking the link you suggested. So may I try executing the jar file under dist folder directly like any other java application? Thanks.

Comment: Well don't see following even after adding `swing-layout-1.0.jar` as given at this link ---Note: You can view the contents of the manifest in the IDE's Files window. After you have built your project, switch to the Files window and navigate to dist/AnotherGrep.jar. Expand the node for the JAR file, expand the META-INF folder, and double-click MANIFEST.MF to display the manifest in the Source Editor.

`Main-Class: anothergrep.xGRep
            Class-Path: lib/swing-layout-1.0.jar`

Comment: Well, I got what was I doing wrong - I was using `SampleProject` as main class whereas it appears in this case, has to be `SampleProjectUI` as main class. It works now. Thanks friends for your suggestions.

Comment: @anujin- sorry bro i went offline. glad your problem is solved. also you can mark it right if it solved your problem :)

Comment: done:) and added an additional step that I followed. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to distribute this application to others and it will be run on different machines. I am just wondering as how could I distribute it?

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> ..sounds cool, would search some tutorials as to see how to use it

The info. page at SO linked above includes the collected knowledge of the SO poster who has the most up-votes for JWS ( me ;) ).  It also includes a list of links to tutorials and other information.

Comment: Andrew, sounds cool, would search some tutorials as to see how to use it. Thanks.