# Trouble creating a runnable jar file in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, filepath, executable-jar

Ive been searching for a couple of days now, and so i decided to turn to the community as a last resort! forgive me if this has been answered before, i have not found anything on it.

For a challenge issued from my computer science teacher for homework, I created a program that finds the absolute path for a specific directory(The Desktop in this case). It then creates a file on the desktop with the absolute desktop path written inside of it and opens a JOptionPane to confirm it has found the directory. I then proceeded to create a runnable jar file by going to "Run>Clean and build project, but when I go to dist and press "Open With Java", it does not run. I understand my code may be inefficient, or it might be "the wrong way to do this", but I would like to find the solution to this problem. I do not know whether my code is necessary, so Ill add it in below:

```
package FileExplorerandFinder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author johnson.william2
 */
public class idk {

static PrintWriter p;
public static boolean onoff = true;

public static void displayFiles(File files[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (files == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (onoff == true) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                if (files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("c:\\Users\\") && files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("Desk") && !files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("All Users") && !files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("Default") && !files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("Public") && !files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("AppData")) {
                    onoff = false;
                    int a = i;
                    p = new PrintWriter(new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath() + "\\FileIndex.txt"));
                    p.println(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    p.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
                displayFiles(files[i].listFiles());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    p = new PrintWriter(new File("c:FileIndex.txt"));
    File afile = new File("c:\\");
    File info[] = afile.listFiles();
    displayFiles(info);
}
}
```

UPDATE:
I figured out the problem searching through the stack overflow questions a couple more hours. The fix ended up being: (Right click the project, Properties, Run, Main Class) the main class was incorrectly selected for some odd reason, no reason as to why it was this way, but I am happy it is fixed. Thanks for the responses guys! Much appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link here
[How to run Java Swing Application outside IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892360/how-to-run-java-swing-application-outside-ide) to add the swing library and build the project.

Then using the command line :

```
java -jar "your jar location E.g. C:\Project\dist\Application.jar"
```

Comment: When I ran the command in the cmd, it returned this error:Could not find or load main class     fileexplorerandfinder.FileExplorerandFinder

Comment: @Yoyomaster223 your main class is not set correctly. For your case, rename the idk class to FileExplorerandFinder will do. Else you need to set the Main class to your idk class and compile. (Project Properties -> Run -> Main class)